# jquery find top level tables in children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find the all table elements that are not descendant of table elements. For example i want to select all these in between **

```
<div>
    <**table**>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        <tr>
            <table>
                ....
            </table>
        </tr>
    </**table**>
    <div>
        <**table**>
            ...
        </**table**>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially i want to find all top level tables and not their descendant tables.
The structure of the DOM is not guaranteed so i can't just use $("div > table")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward solution is to select all tables and filter out those that have a table ancestor:

```
var $tables = $("table")
                .filter(function() { return $(this).parents("table").length == 0; });
```

Comment: no need to for the `== 0`. Besides, it should be `=== 0`. If the length returns 0 it will be false, so a simple `!` in front will do

Comment: @TimVermaelen: No need but when targeted to newbies I prefer it to a `!` in front, which I would use for myself. And I don't see why it "should" be identity. In any case those are really secondary matters and do not affect the meat of the answer.

Comment: there is a bug in your code. Closest includes current element so the check should be  == 1 instead of 0 (which would never return true)

Comment: Ofcourse, the meat of the answer seems good to me. In fact, it's what I was going to suggest. But I don't understand why someone with your reputation points teaches the "newbies" the half right way ... it's a pity tbh ... :s Putting it in a one-liner helps to copy/pasting?

Comment: @zaftcoAgeiha: Thanks for catching this, `parents` is correct.

Comment: @TimVermaelen: I really don't think it's half right, just a matter of preference.

Comment: If I'm right, you just created a double overhead, `==` has to compare two values instead of one and has to compare numbers to strings. Who knows, I may be completely wrong here ...

Comment: @TimVermaelen: There is no string involved in this comparison. As for the type comparison (to determine if a conversion is required), `===` has to make that as well (to determine if it should fail outright).

Comment: You're probably right, Jon. I'll keep this minor issue I have to myself from now on ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can select all the tables that don't have a child table element

```
$("table:not(:has(table))")
```

Comment: mmm but thats not what i want. I dont want tables that have tables as their parent.

Answer (score 1):

ok consider this:

```
$("table").addClass("test"); // add new class to all the tables <br/><br/>
$("tr").children().removeClass("test"); // remove this class for all the children of tr<br/><br/>
$("td").children().removeClass("test"); // remove this class for all the children of td<br/><br/>
$(".test") //now select the upper most table with its class
```

Comment: Give an example to be a bit more helpful.

Comment: the reason is because i dont control the html